# Renaming object or element in perticular range in a column of text file

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, command-line

To expand on my previous question, I have another pattern of a file,  I  am trying to change the name of first column ranging from seq1 to seq20 (seq1-seq20) as seq1 similarly ranging from seq21 to seq60 (seq21-seq60)as seq2. File name is file.txt anf the following format is:

```
seq22 19301 20914 fill_color=green_a0
seq55 16726 18337 fill_color=green_a0
seq10 167934 169650 fill_color=green_a0
seq36 200621 202367 fill_color=red_a0
seq7 160164 161903 fill_color=green_a0
seq56 31356 33104 fill_color=green_a0
seq25 15030 16656 fill_color=green_a0
seq43 99693 101326 fill_color=red_a0
seq19 66168 67689 fill_color=green_a0
seq50 55955 57479 fill_color=green_a0
seq9 454456 456277 fill_color=green_a0
seq35 282633 284453 fill_color=green_a0
seq10 354264 355872 fill_color=green_a0
seq36 10125 11742 fill_color=red_a0
seq3 106668 110910 fill_color=green_a0
```

Output file look like

```
seq2 19301 20914 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 16726 18337 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 167934 169650 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 200621 202367 fill_color=red_a0
seq1 160164 161903 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 31356 33104 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 15030 16656 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 99693 101326 fill_color=red_a0
seq1 66168 67689 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 55955 57479 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 454456 456277 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 282633 284453 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 354264 355872 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 10125 11742 fill_color=red_a0
seq1 106668 110910 fill_color=green_a0
```

I tried with this

```
sed -e "s/seq[1:20]*/seq1/" -e "s/seq[21:60]*/seq2/" file.txt
```

and

```
awk 'NR>=seq1 && NR<=seq20{sub("seq*","seq1",$0)} 1' file.txt
```

Comment: what *are* the programming / scripting languages that you are familiar with? Because all this suggests you will have to write more software to actually deal with this data later on, and it's a bit surprising you need to do these processing steps outside of that.

Comment: also, it's absolutely not clear how you decide what becomes `seq1` and what becomes `seq2`.

Comment: I suggest to replace `reanging` with `ranging` in your question.

Comment: Please clarify how `seqNN` becomes either `seq1` or `seq2`. Are the first two `seq2` in a row a typo?

Comment: I assume in your desired output `seq1 15030 16656 fill_color=green_a0` is a bug.

Comment: I have edited question as per the suggestion. Can I do it using loop. If possible kindly help me. I know this linux bash only a bit. It will help me to learn a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1); if($1+0<21){$1="seq1"} else {$1="seq2"}; print}' file
```

`gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1)` removes all but numbers from first column.

Comment: Thank you its working, can I ask why u use [^0-9] and how it work, and also $1+0<21 , whats the use of + here

Comment: I [removed a space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739449/revisions) in `gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1)`. It was a typo.
`[^0-9]` is a regex which matches on all characters which are not (`^`) numbers (`0-9`). With `$1+0` I force $1 from a string to a number. Then it is checked whether `$1` is smaller than `21`.

Answer (score 0):

Both your description and your attempts look weird, but given the input and desired output I think you want this:

```
$ awk '(NR%2==1) ? $1="seq2" :$1="seq1"' file.txt
seq2 19301 20914 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 16726 18337 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 167934 169650 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 200621 202367 fill_color=red_a0
seq2 160164 161903 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 31356 33104 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 15030 16656 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 99693 101326 fill_color=red_a0
seq2 66168 67689 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 55955 57479 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 454456 456277 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 282633 284453 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 354264 355872 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 10125 11742 fill_color=red_a0
seq2 106668 110910 fill_color=green_a0
```

Comment: I have huge data in a file for example I kept small portion, I wanted to replace name if it is seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4...........seq20 with seq1 and similarly seq21, seq22,seq23...........seq60 with seq2 . kindly suggest to improve my question. I did maximum from myside. Thanks and regards